# Obtengo el mensaje : "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread", usando Retrofit con Android

Tags: android, hilos, retrofit

Buenas tengo este método para obtener el response:

```
public void cargarFilas(String filtro){

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2/api/"+filtro+"/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    apiService= retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    Call<Usuario_Fila> call = apiService.list(txtBuscar.getText().toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Usuario_Fila>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Usuario_Fila> call, Response<Usuario_Fila> response) {
            if (response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                datos = response.body();
                Usuario_Adaptador_Busqueda adaptador = new Usuario_Adaptador_Busqueda(Usuario_BusquedaActivity.this, datos.getFila());
                list.setAdapter(adaptador);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Usuario_Fila> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(Usuario_BusquedaActivity.this, "Fallo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

El problema es que la actividad donde se ejecuta el método se pone muy lenta y tarda mucho hasta en darle a un botón. Me aparece esto en el log:

> I/Choreographer(1378): Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: la verdad no me ha pasado algo parecido pero yo ando utilizando RxJava junto con retrofit, con eso creo que podrías evitar que tengas muchas operaciones en el hilo principal, aun que yo creo que lo que consume recursos de tu aplicacion ha de ser otra cosa y no retrofit

Comment: Te recomiendo capturar el StackTrace para obtener la descripción completa del (o los) error(es). Agrega mas información: ¿qué hace el método que se demora tanto?, etc. Saludos

Comment: Esto es simple. Debes ejecutar la tarea que demora mucho en un thread diferente al principal.  Pasate por acá https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**The application may be doing too much work on its main thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)

Esto en realidad no es un error, pero es una advertencia, como la descripción lo indica, se esta realizando mucho procesamiento en el hilo principal.

> Para arreglar esto, es necesario identificar los puntos donde haya o
>   posiblemente ocurra una larga duración de procesamiento. **La mejor
>   manera es hacer todo el procesamiento no importa cuán pequeño o grande
>   en un hilo separado del hilo principal de la interfaz de usuario.** Así
>   sea acceder a los datos de una base de datos SQLite o hacer
>   algunas operaciones matemáticas hardcore o simplemente ordenar un array
>   - **Realizarlo en un Thread diferente.**

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html