# Escribir String en fichero en red

Tags: java, android, android-studio

me gustaría hacer una especie de formulario con este código enviando "cadena_envio" pero no consigo hacer que la escriba en el fichero.

```
    public void envio_formulario(View v){
        String nombre=et_nonm.getText().toString();
        String telefono=et_telf.getText().toString();
        String email=et_email.getText().toString();
        String comentario=et_coment.getText().toString();

        cadena_envio="Nombre: "+nombre+" Email: "+email+" Telefono: "+telefono+" Comentario: "+comentario+"\n";
        Toast.makeText(this,cadena_envio,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Thread hilo_escribe = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    URL url = new URL("http://radios-android.000webhostapp.com/formulario.txt");
                    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                    OutputStream is = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(is));
                    bw.write(cadena_envio);
                    bw.close();
                }catch (Exception e){}
            }
        });
        hilo_escribe.start();

        try{
            hilo_escribe.join();
        }catch (Exception e){}


    }
}
```

Comment: Que error te da el log?

Comment: Al pulsar enviar me sale esto: `05-08 23:07:55.899 22810-3811/mazcvei.radiosespana I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
    (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
05-08 23:07:56.499 22810-22810/mazcvei.radiosespana I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` @RaulCacacho

Comment: mira este link te ayudara [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67790/obtengo-el-mensaje-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thr)

Comment: Veo que se soluciona creando un hilo, pero ya lo creo para conectar con el fichero, y no hay nada más en la actividad :(

Comment: @MarioAzcVei quieres escribir contenido en : http://radios-android.000webhostapp.com/formulario.txt ? si es así esto es incorrecto.

Comment: Si @Jorgesys, qué habría que hacer entonces?

Comment: @MarioAzcVei usa FTP o una página que pueda escribir en el archivo, directamente esto no es posible.

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente este tipo de operaciones no las debes realizar en el thread pricipal, puedes usar un `Asynctask` para llamar tu método, ejemplo:

```
 private class LeeArchivos extends AsyncTask<Void , Integer, Long>{
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            return procesoEscritura;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
          //Termina proceso
            Log.i("TAG" , "Termina proceso de escritura.");
        }
    }
```

Ahora bien, si el objetivo es escribir en un archivo puedes realizarlo usando FTP, para esto puedes usar [**SimpleFTP**](http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/)

De otra forma puedes enviar lo que deseas escribir en el archivo via `POST` y que una pagina PHP, ASP, JSP, etc escriba en el archivo, como indica esta respuesta en el sitio en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585728/write-data-to-a-text-file-on-url-in-android