# Error depurando en Android Studio. No se para en los puntos de parada

Tags: java, android-studio, depuración

El depurador de Android Studio no funciona como debería. Llevo depurando bien durante todo este tiempo pero ya no lo hace adecuadamente. Al hacer click sobre el icono de depurar `Debug 'app'`, la app se inicializa en el dispositivo, pero no se para en los puntos de parada que establezco.

Me aparecen mensajes en la línea de comandos que quizá tengan algo que ver:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Como os comento, la app se ejecuta con normalidad y funciona correctamente, pero el debugger no se para en los breakpoints.

Comment: Haz click en el icono de `Attach Debugger` y verifica que el depurador se haya agregado al proceso de tu App. A veces me ha pasado que se crean varios procesos, uno que está IDLE o DIED, que no es el actual, en ese caso debes cambiar al actual. Si no funciona, dale a Stop (cuadro rojo) para parar todos los procesos y luego a Debug, o, en último término, cierra y abre de nuevo Android Studio.

Comment: Verifica que estas adjuntando la depuración  y el mensaje "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." se debe a otra razón diferente, agregué las posibles causas por las cuales no se pueden reconocer los "break point".

Answer (score 0):

Si tu aplicación no se detiene en los "Breakpoint", esto puede deberse a varias causas, te sugiero revisar él [artículo de Elye](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/when-your-android-studio-breakpoint-doesnt-stop-cf0331e63dd2#:%7E:text=Hence%20when%20you%20put%20a,of%20Thread%20as%20shown%20below.), en donde se elistan las razones:

**1. ¿Es accesible la línea de código?**
A veces nunca se llega a la línea de código en particular, ya que estamos demasiado absortos en depurar el problema, sin darnos cuenta de que nunca se llega al código.

Puede haber varias razones:

- Ponemos el código en una clase diferente que se ve igual.
- Estamos ejecutando otra variante de la aplicación que no está adjunta a la depuración (`Attach Debugger`).
- Estamos ejecutando en otro dispositivo que no está conectado a la depuración.

**2. ¿Está habilitado el punto de interrupción?**
Esto probablemente sea simple si estas familiarizado con Android Studio.

Pero en caso de que se así, a continuación se muestra la indicación de los iconos de punto de interrupción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para los dos primeros, eso significa que todos son buenos. A veces, debido a fallas en Android Studio, el punto de interrupción no se muestra adjunto, pero podría estar bien.

**3. ¿Estas ejecutando en modo de depuración?**

A diferencia de iOS Xcode, en Android Studio, para depurar su aplicación, deberas ejecutarla en modo de depuración (debug).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra en el diagrama anterior, asegúrese de estar ejecutando la aplicación presionando el ícono Depurar. Si lo olvidas, aún puedes adjuntar el depurador más tarde.

**4. ¿Está ejecutando Debug Build?**
Para depurar, debe asegurarse de ejecutar su aplicación en la variante de compilación de depuración, como se muestra a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Técnicamente, incluso si lo ejecuta en la versión de lanzamiento, aún se detendrá y se interrumpirá en su punto de interrupción.

Es posible que no pueda ver el valor de la variable o evaluar cualquier expresión correctamente. Esto se debe a que, de forma predeterminada, la variante de lanzamiento está configurada para minificar habilitada ( `minifyEnabled true`) y protegida (código si está ofuscado). Ejemplo:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
            'proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

**5. ¿Está habilitado el punto de interrupción en el subproceso?
Este podría ser el problema más golpeado por muchos.**

En Android, podemos ejecutar nuestro código en el hilo principal o en el hilo de fondo. Si no me equivoco, el punto de interrupción de depuración solo se interrumpirá en el hilo principal.

Por lo tanto, cuando coloca un punto de interrupción en el código que se ejecuta en segundo plano, no se detendrá.

Para asegurarse de que su punto de interrupción se detenga en todos los subprocesos, vaya a la configuración de su punto de interrupción (haga clic con el botón derecho en el punto de interrupción), configúrelo en Todo en lugar de Subproceso, como se muestra a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**6. ¿Se está ejecutando en un proceso diferente?**
Este será el que hará que uno tire del cabello hasta que se caiga, aún así no funcionará si no lo sabe. No hay ninguna indicación en Android Studio de que este conjunto de puntos de interrupción no se detenga. Esto es independientemente de si lo ha configurado en Todos los subprocesos o no.

En Android, nuestra aplicación normalmente se ejecuta en el proceso principal, independientemente del hilo principal o el hilo de fondo.

Pero en alguna ocasión, podemos hacer que parte de nuestra aplicación funcione en un proceso diferente, de modo que no muera cuando la aplicación finalice. Ejemplo: el siguiente servicio se indica como otro proceso.

```
<servicio android:name="com.example.myapplication_sync.MainService"
          android:proceso=":otroProceso" />
```

Un marco popular para este proceso es [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter). Si revisa el documento, podrá ver que está configurado para procesar  `process=":sync"`

Fuente: [**Cuando su punto de interrupción de Android Studio no se detiene**](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/when-your-android-studio-breakpoint-doesnt-stop-cf0331e63dd2#:%7E:text=Hence%20when%20you%20put%20a,of%20Thread%20as%20shown%20below.)

---

Con respecto al mensaje:

**The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.**

te sugiero revisar:

[Obtengo el mensaje : "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread", usando Retrofit con Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67790/obtengo-el-mensaje-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thr)

y

[The application may be doing too much work on its main thread (inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21126690/250260)