# kotlin Firebase Skipped 45 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

tengo un llamado sencillo a Firebase pero me da el error de:
Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

ya verifique que la ruta dentro de firebase sea esa  y todo pinta bien de ese lado
de hecho en otro fragmente dentro de la aplicacion le hago un push y me da el resultado sin problemas

todo esta dentro de un fragment
hice una funcion sencilla para asegurarme si estaba funcionando la conexion pero nada
asi queda mi codigo de prueba pero no me devuelve nada

```
 private fun funcionprueba()  {


        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val ref = Firebase.database.reference.child("user").child(uid.toString()).child("CalendarioUser")
        Log.d("prueba", "empezando  a tirar piedras")
        ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if ( snapshot.exists()){
                    val child = snapshot.child("nombreUsuario").value

                    Log.d("calendar", " funcionando " + child)
                }else{
                    Log.e("calendar", "esto no esta funcionando")
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e("galery","error con firebase: $error")
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje:

> The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

En realidad es un aviso el cual indica que se está realizando mucho procesamiento en el Thread principal, es importan que el proceso `funcionprueba()` y otros que tengas en tu app se realicen usando [**Corutinas de Kotlin en Android**](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?hl=es-419) .

Revisa: [Obtengo el mensaje : "the application may be doing too much work on its main thread", usando Retrofit con Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/67790/obtengo-el-mensaje-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thr)